# Using jquery selectors in an expect in jasmine

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I've noticed that you when writing jasmine unit tests usually the format is:

```
expect($('#foo')).toHaveValue('#bar');
```

But recently I've discovered by accident that the following also works:

```
expect('#foo').toHaveValue('#bar');
```

Is this expected behaviour? This seems like a better way to write my expects but I have never seen this notation before and I want to be sure I am not abusing something.

Could anyone confirm this is the way to go or direct me to any documentation of this?

(I am using the [jasmine jquery library](https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've played around a bit with that. Looks like it really does work, having some peculiarities, though.

I've tried things like:

```
expect('.search-form').toBeInDOM();
expect('.search-form').toEqual('div');
expect('.search-form').toContainElement('.search-form__footer');
```

- the first one passes and truely fails when changing to
  `.not.toBeInDOM();`
- the third one looks same -- it truely fails is    changing to some
  bad selector for `toContainElement`
- the second one is a problem because of ambiguity: `'.search-form'` can be treated both as string and a selector.

Had a very brief look into source code, it looks likes matchers really do resolve expectation actual as a selector (example [from](https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery/blob/master/lib/jasmine-jquery.js#L442)):

```
toBeInDOM: function () {
    return {
      compare: function (actual) {
        return { pass: $.contains(document.documentElement, $(actual)[0]) }
      }
    }
  },
```

Although I could not find any sign of such abilities in [their docs](https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery), too. Still, source code is source code ))) and it says what it says. And now it says it will treat the actual for `expect` as a selector.

Comment: I guess it makes sense that the library that provided jquery matchers also provided this. Thanks a lot for the insight!